# Check SSIS Connection Manager's access to Server and DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a table with three fields like,

```
Server-Name ------          DB-Name -------            Flag
ABC ------------------ ABC123 
XYZ ------------------ 123XYZ
EFG ------------------ ABCXY5
YUI -------------------  TER675
```

I save that table's details in a variable and have attached a for each loop container to dynamically  assign server and db names to the connection manager of a data flow task in the for each loop container. Now the new requirement is to update the field "Flag" in the table to "1", if

1. The server and DB exists
2. My login has the access to that server-db combinations.

and if any of the above two conditions fails, update the Flag to "0" and send the users with that respective details.

How do I update the field "Flag", in the table based on the above two conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a script task before executing the for each loop and iterate through the the settings?

Then in the script you can have a simple test that tries to create a connection

```
...
string connectionString = "from your Object var";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
...
```

wrap the above in a try/catch and update the Flag based on whether an exception occurs or not. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8098124/217981) on how to use the Object variable in your script task

Comment: I am so sorry i have a very little knowledge on scripting. Can you please provide the code? Moreover, how do i iterate through the settings before the for each loop? Do i use another for each loop ?