# SSIS send email using external xml template

Tags: c#, t-sql, xslt, ssis

I need to send emails from an SSIS package, but the with email content in the form of an external xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EmailContent>
<FromMailId>johndoe@email.com</FromMailId>
    <CC>janedoe@email.com</CC>
<BCC></BCC>
<EmailSubject>Email Subject Line</EmailSubject>
<EmailBody>
    Email Body here with some $variables$.   
    </EmailBody>
</EmailContent>
```

I set up a test project where I'm using a SQL script task to save to a **ResultObject**. Then inside a **ForEachLoopContainer** I have a **SendMailTask**. There are different email templates that need to be sent based upon a value from the **ResultObject**. I need to check a variable in the ResultObject, and then based upon that value grab the corresponding email xml template. I'm guessing I need to achieve this using a C# **ScriptTask** instead of the **SendMailTask**, but I'm not sure how?

**UPDATE**

I am writing a **ScriptTask** to copy the xml node values to variables. But I am receiving blank values? See code below:

```
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(email.xml);
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load(reader);

        string EmailTo = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("EmailContent/FromMailId").InnerText;
        string EmailCc = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("EmailContent/CC").Value;
```

Comment: Right now, this question is rather broad.   Can you isolate more specifically what it is you're not sure how to do?  Is it this?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096750/how-to-loop-through-a-generic-object-in-ssis-script-task

Comment: in your C# code, EmailCc needs to be xDoc.SelectSingleNode("EmailContent/CC").InnerText as well. How did you assign the value back to variables? I think you are on the right track, the SendMail task can be parameterized, just go to expression tab and set toline, ccline, etc with your dynamic values.