# SSIS - Various number of columns to output to flat file

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I am currently creating an SSIS that will gather data from database and output it to a single Comma delimited Flat File. The file will contain order details Format of file is

```
Order#1 details (51 columns)
Order#1 header  (62 columns)
Order#2 details (51 columns)
Order#2 header  (62 columns)
etc...
```

Order header has 62 columns, order details has 51 columns. I need to output this to a flat file and I am running into an issue because SSIS does not handle varying columns. Can someone please help me and given that my source is an OLEDB source with the query, how do I create a script component to output to a file.

Current Package looks like the following:

1. Get a list of all order. Pass orderid as a variable.
2. For loop container goes through each orderid, runs a data task flow to get the order details for the order. Run a data task to get order header. 
   I am just running into an issue to output each line to Flat file.

IF anyone can help that will be immensely appreciated. I have been struggling with this for a week now.If anyone can start me off with what the script component code should look like that would be immensely appreciated.

I have added what I have so far:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDUO6.jpg

This is what my script looks like:

```
public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here
        DataTable RecordType300 = new DataTable();
        DataTable RecordType210 = new DataTable();
        DataTable RecordType220 = new DataTable();
        DataTable RecordType200 = new DataTable();

        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        adapter.Fill(RecordType300, Dts.Variables["User:rec_type300"].Value);
        adapter.Fill(RecordType210, Dts.Variables["User::rec_type_210"].Value);
        adapter.Fill(RecordType220, Dts.Variables["User::rec_type_220"].Value);
        adapter.Fill(RecordType200, Dts.Variables["User::rec_type200"].Value);
        using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter("C:\\myoutput.csv"))
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < RecordType300.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                var detailFields = RecordType300.Rows[i].ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString()).ToArray();
               // var poBillFields = RecordType210.Rows[i].ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString()).ToArray();
              //  var poShipFields = RecordType220.Rows[i].ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString()).ToArray();
             //   var poHeaderFields = RecordType200.Rows[i].ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString()).ToArray();
                outfile.WriteLine(String.Join(",", detailFields));
              //  outfile.WriteLine(string.Join(",", poBillFields));
              //  outfile.WriteLine(string.Join(",", poShipFields));
              //  outfile.WriteLine(string.Join(",", poHeaderFields));
            }
        }

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;

    }
```

But every time I run it, it errors out. Am I missing something here? Also, how would I create a file in the beginning only 1 time. Meaning every time this package is run it will create a file with the datestamp and append to it each time. The next time the package runs, it will create a new file with new date stamp and append each order details based on the order number.

Comment: I think you are on the right track with the script idea. Look into putting your results from the header and details into two separate DataTables. See this link as an example of how to fill and iterate over them. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14103080

Comment: @Sorrell. Currently I do have two separate data tables. The problem I am running into is actually creating the script.

Comment: The usual workaround for ragged files is to export the data as _one_ column that just happens to contain a bunch of data that is comma seperated. You can write a single query to generate and export this but it depends whether you are more comfortable with T-SQL or C#. IMHO the C# / Lookup approach is convoluted and disconnected. I prefer to write one SQL query that does all the work (efficiently) and exports it

Comment: I like the idea @Nick.McDermaid presents.  You could create a table with (ponumber, filetype, csvcontents (max varchar)).  So then you might have 4 entries for PO# 1 (#1_detail filetype, #2_bill filetype, #3)ship filetype, #4_header filetype).  Then in your SQL, `ORDER BY PONUMBER, FILETYPE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code/method has not been tested but should give you a good idea of what to do.

1. Create 2 SSIS variables of type object, one for the headers and one for the detail. [image: Variables]
2. Create 2 `Execute SQL` tasks and 1 `Script Task` as outlined here: [image: Overview]
3. Setup your Tasks to handle a full result set, similar to these pics (the Detail version is shown, do similar for Header but map results to the Header object and change your query to point at the header table): [image: ExecSql] [image: ExecSql2]
4. Edit your script task and allow `Detail` and `Header` as read only vars: [image: ReadOnlyVars]
5. Edit your actual script now along these lines (this is assuming you have exactly 1 detail row for 1 header row):

> 

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.OleDb;

// following to be inserted into Main() function
DataTable detailData = new DataTable();
DataTable headerData = new DataTable();
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
adapter.Fill(detailData, Dts.Variables["User::Detail"].Value);
adapter.Fill(headerData, Dts.Variables["User::Header"].Value);

using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter("myoutput.csv"))
{
    // we are making the assumption that 
    for (var i = 0; i < detailData.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        var detailFields = detailData.Rows[i].ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString()).ToArray();
        var headerFields = headerData.Rows[i].ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString()).ToArray();
        outfile.WriteLine(string.Join(",", detailFields));
        outfile.WriteLine(string.Join(",", headerFields));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is really really great. However, I didn't want to pull data from a script as I have to perform additional look ups. For example, before this is output, I have to perform a lookup on the Company Name.

Comment: If I have it to execute the SQL task script, then I will not be able to make changes to the column.

Comment: Anything you can do in the data flow can be done with SQL and C#. For example, instead of a lookup, can you restructure your query to join to the Company table to grab the name? If so then that column is part of your result set. Deriving and calculation can also be done with SQL and/or C#.

Comment: @Sorell I have updated the file and added additional comments. I tired to use the same logic, but it errors out at the script component aspect. Please let me know if you have any input. In particular there seems to be an issue with the Variables aspect.

Comment: @Sorell I think the error falls under the variable: adapter.Fill(RecordType300, Dts.Variables["User::rec_type300"].Value);
or any of the similar variables when its trying to retrieve the objects. 
Essentially the error is exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Not even sure what that means.

Comment: @a415 Are you sure that you've set `rec_type300` as the variable for the Full Result Set?  Sounds like that variable doesnt have data?

Comment: I did. I managed to get this working. Your idea worked great. Had to modify the code at the end though. Get column by column instead.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, just something to put you on the track of an alternative approach

```
SELECT Type, OrderBy, Col
FROM
(
   SELECT 'D' As Type, Ord as OrderBy, 
   Col1 + ',' + CAST(Col2 AS VARCHAR(50)) + ',' + Col3 As Col
   FROM Details
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'H' As Type, Ord as OrderBy,
   Col1 + ',' + CAST(Col2 AS VARCHAR(50)) + ',' + Col3 As Col + ',' + Col4
   FROM Header
) S
ORDER BY OrderBy, Type
```

Its ugly but it works as long as you cast all datatypes to varchar

You can wrap this up in a view or a stored procedure and test it from the database (before you get to the SSIS part). You can even export this using BCP.EXE rather than SSIS

What you have here is one column which happens to contain this kind of data:

```
 A,B,C
 D,E,F,G
```

From a metadata perspective there is consistently one column

From a CSV perspective there are variable columns