# ssis control flow execute sql vs data flow sql command

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, ssis, ssis-2008

I have a stored procedure(`sp_selectClient`) having a cursor which is performing some insert operations in every iteration. In last statement of sp I selected the result from a table.

Now I am creating a ssis package and I am new in this. I found the simplest way by adding Data Flow Task in Control Flow and then inside Data Flow I added one `source(OLEDB)` in which I set the SQL Command `'EXEC sp_selectClient'`. The stored procedure do not accept any parameters. And then I mapped it into `destination(flat file)`. My query is can I do this with `Execute SQL Task` also. If yes then what are the advantages and disadvantage of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes** you can do the same with **Execute SQL task** also.

*OLE DB Command inside data flow task:* Will always process the data row by row

*Execute SQL task in control flow:* will process the data in bulk

[What is the difference between Execute SQL Task and OLE DB Command](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e804bdcd-ad03-402e-ad93-fc74a60d87a2/what-is-the-difference-between-execute-sql-task-and-ole-db-command?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

Answer (score 0):

If your Stored procedure create a result set, you can do this using Execute SQL Task and storing the Resultsets inside a variable of type `Object` Then looping over rows inside a `Script Task`.

These are usefuls links that helps you to store `ResultSets` inside a variable and loop over its rows inside a `Script Task`:

- [How to loop through a generic object in SSIS Script Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096750/how-to-loop-through-a-generic-object-in-ssis-script-task)
- [Implementing Foreach Looping Logic in SSIS](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/implementing-foreach-looping-logic-in-ssis/)
- [Execute SQL Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bebb2e8c-0410-43b2-ac2f-6fc80c8f2e9e)

**If your stored procedure does not produce any ResultSets (*Select command*) it is best practice to use an Execute SQL Task**

The `OLE DB Command` runs insert, update or delete statements for each row, while the `Execute SQL Task` does a Bulk Insert in this instance.  That means every single row that goes through your package would have an insert statement run when it gets to an `OLE DB Command`.

**References:**

- [SSIS – Avoid OLE DB Command](http://bidn.com/blogs/DevinKnight/ssis/91/ssis-avoid-ole-db-command)